# why vector<T> v{}; calls the default initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

From [CppReference Value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> This is the initialization performed when an object is constructed
> with an empty initializer.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> (1)   T ()
> (2)   new T ()
> (3)   Class::Class(...) : member () { ... }
> (4)   T object {}; (since C++11)
> (5)   T {} (since C++11)
> (6)   new T {} (since C++11)
> (7)   Class::Class(...) : member {} { ... } (since C++11)
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Value initialization is performed in these situations:
>
> - (1), (5) when a nameless temporary object is created with the initializer    consisting of an empty pair of parentheses or braces
>   (since C++11);
> - (2), (6) when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a    new-expression with the initializer consisting of an empty pair of
>   parentheses or braces (since C++11);
> - (3), (7) when a non-static data    member or a base class is initialized using a member initializer with    an empty pair of
>   parentheses or braces (since C++11);
> - (4) (since    C++11) when a named object (automatic, static, or thread-local) is    declared with the initializer consisting of a pair
>   of braces.

This is fine as `vector<T> v{};` seems has syntax (4).

Then it says

> **The effects of value initialization are:**
>
> - 1. if T is a class type with no default constructor or with a user-declared (until
>      C++11)user-provided or deleted (since C++11) default constructor, the
>      object is default-initialized;
> - 2. if T is a class type with a default
>      constructor that is not user-declared (until C++11)neither
>      user-provided nor deleted (since C++11)  (that is, it may be a class
>      with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor),  the
>      object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for
>      default-initialization are checked,  and if T has a non-trivial
>      default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
> - 3. if T is an
>      array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;
> - 4. otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

I assume this falls into case 2 as `vector<T>` has a default constructor that takes 0 parameter. Then this 'vector v' shall be zero-initialized, instead of default-initialized?

Comment: "*that is not user-declared (until C++11)neither user-provided nor deleted*" Did you miss this part?

Comment: @NicolBolas but normally `vector<T>` default constructor won't be user-declared or user-provided  or deleted , as it's the standard library, user won't touch it, right?

Comment: `T` can be a user defined class.

Comment: @athos: When they say "user-declared", they don't mean declared by *you*. "User-declared" is a specific concept in the standard, and `vector`'s default constructor qualifies. That is, the standard library declares a default constructor with certain behavior, and that counts as "user-declared" because that's what "user-declared" means. While the standard library is allowed to do "magic" things the user isn't, that's only relative to the behavior of particular functions. From the perspective of the language, the library is still mostly a client of the language.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well technically the c++ standard doesn't define the term "user-declared". See [CWG 2632](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2632.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that, as of now, the C++ Standard does not technically define the meaning of the term, **user-declared**. This is addressed in [CWG 2632](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2632.html)

> I assume this falls into case 2

No, this falls into case 1 because `std::vector<T>`has a [user-provided] default constructor (whose definition depends on user-declared constructor).

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ standard, types in `std` can be "user-declared".

At one point this was ambiguous, as different parts of the standard used similar verbage for both "written by an end user" and "not part of a fundamental type".  Now, "user-declared" unambiguously includes `std::vector::vector` and similar.

Probably they should consider changing the name.